# cannot fetch records from mongo collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb

i am new to nodejs and my first question on stackoverflow 
In my application a database named  passport has two collection both stored in
users  for storing login information & buyers for storing buyers information.
In my server.js i have following code

```
         var configDB = require('./config/database.js');
         app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
          app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
           mongoose.connect(configDB.url); 
                   // connect to our database
           require('./config/passport')(passport);
                     ........
                     ........ 


 **My routes.js content are**



var buyer = require('./models/buyer.js');//make sure you write directory path correctly
module.exports = function(app, passport) {
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
// normal routes ===============================================================

    // show the home page (will also have our login links)
    app.get('/', function(req, res) {
        res.render('index.ejs');
    });


 // locally --------------------------------
        // LOGIN ===============================
        // show the login form
        app.get('/login', function(req, res) {
            res.render('login.ejs', { message: req.flash('loginMessage') });
        });

        // process the login form
        app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local-login', {
            successRedirect : '/profile', // redirect to the secure profile section
            failureRedirect : '/login', // redirect back to the signup page if there is an error
            failureFlash : true // allow flash messages
        }));

         // SIGNUP =================================
        // show the signup form
        app.get('/signup', function(req, res) {
            res.render('signup.ejs', { message: req.flash('signupMessage') });
        });

        // process the signup form
        app.post('/signup', passport.authenticate('local-signup', {
            successRedirect : '/profile', // redirect to the secure profile section
            failureRedirect : '/signup', // redirect back to the signup page if there is an error
            failureFlash : true // allow flash messages
        }));


    // PROFILE SECTION =========================
    app.get('/profile',  function(req, res) {
        res.render('profile.ejs', {
            user : req.user
        });
    });




app.get('/views/transaction.ejs',function(req,res){
return  res.render('transaction.ejs');
});



//THIS IS MY SCHEMA FOR TRANSACTION SUBMIT


var buyerSchema = new mongoose.Schema({ 

       Tr_id: String,
       //userID : String ,
    SellerBank   : String,
    SellerAccountno: String,
    SellerName   : String,
    Amount:Number



//your_schema
}, { collection : 'buyer'});
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var buyerModel = mongoose.model('buyer', buyerSchema);

//it is request through form submit button on action /addbulletein

app.post('/addbulletin', function(req, res){

function randomNumber(len) {
    var randomNumber;
    var n = '';

    for(var count = 0; count < len; count++) {
        randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
        n += randomNumber.toString();
    }
    return n;
};

var Tr_id = randomNumber(9);

var Tr_id=Tr_id;
//var userID=user._id,

/// is this correct way to get input  ???????????
 var  SellerBank = req.body.SellerBank;
 var SellerAccountno = req.body.SellerAccontno;
 var SellerName = req.body.Amount;


//DB INFO : var url='mongodb://localhost/passport' 
//trying to insert all the param


db.collection('buyer').insert({
"SellerBank":SellerBank,
"Tr_id":Tr_id,
 "SellerBank": SellerBank ,
 "SellerAccountno":SellerAccountno,
"SellerName":SellerName


},function(err,doc){
if(err)throw err;
});

});

app.get('/viewall',function(req,res)
{
    //now here below buyer is available as a model to use directly
  buyerModel.find({},function(err,docs){
   if(err){
    res.json(err);
   }
   else{
    res.render('display', { users : docs });
   }
});



 });


    // LOGOUT ==============================
    app.get('/logout', function(req, res) {
        req.logout();
        res.redirect('/');
    });

// =============================================================================
// AUTHENTICATE (FIRST LOGIN) ==================================================
// =============================================================================

    // locally --------------------------------
        // LOGIN ===============================
        // show the login form
        app.get('/login', function(req, res) {
            res.render('login.ejs', { message: req.flash('loginMessage') });
        });

        // process the login form
        app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local-login', {
            successRedirect : '/profile', // redirect to the secure profile section
            failureRedirect : '/login', // redirect back to the signup page if there is an error
            failureFlash : true // allow flash messages
        }));

        // SIGNUP =================================
        // show the signup form
        app.get('/signup', function(req, res) {
            res.render('signup.ejs', { message: req.flash('signupMessage') });
        });

        // process the signup form
        app.post('/signup', passport.authenticate('local-signup', {
            successRedirect : '/profile', // redirect to the secure profile section
            failureRedirect : '/signup', // redirect back to the signup page if there is an error
            failureFlash : true // allow flash messages
        }));

// =============================================================================
// AUTHORIZE (ALREADY LOGGED IN / CONNECTING OTHER SOCIAL ACCOUNT) =============
// =============================================================================

    // locally --------------------------------
        app.get('/connect/local', function(req, res) {
            res.render('connect-local.ejs', { message: req.flash('loginMessage') });
        });
        app.post('/connect/local', passport.authenticate('local-signup', {
            successRedirect : '/profile', // redirect to the secure profile section
            failureRedirect : '/connect/local', // redirect back to the signup page if there is an error
            failureFlash : true // allow flash messages
        }));

   //route middleware to ensure user is logged in
function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {
   if (req.isAuthenticated())
        return next();

    res.redirect('/');
};

    };
```

> **My contents of buyer.js are**

```
                        var mongoose = require('mongoose');
                          var buyerSchema = new mongoose.Schema({ 
                     Tr_id: String,
                      //userID : String ,
                             SellerBank   : String,
                           SellerAccountno: String,
                          SellerName   : String,
                    Amount:Number
                    //your_schema
                         }, { collection : 'buyer'});

               var buyerModel = mongoose.model('buyer', buyerSchema);
```

**I also have a html form which invokes app.post('/addbulletin', function(req, res){**

> **contents of html page is**

```
<html>
<body>

<a href="/trhistory" class="btn btn-default"><span class="fa fa-user"></span>display</a>

<form action="/addbulletin" method="POST">
 SellerBank:<br>
  <input type="text" name="SellerBank" value="">
  <br>
  SellerAccountno:<br>
  <input type="text" name="SellerAccountno" value="">
  <br>
  SellerName:<br>
  <input type="text" name="SellerName" value="">
  <br>
  Amount:<br>
  <input type="number" name="Amount" value="">
  <br>
  Application:<br>

   <input type="file" id="myFile">
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="submit transaction">

</form> 
</body>
</html>
```

**when click on submit button  of my html page  it redirects to /addbuletien and throw error   ReferenceError: db is not defined**

Answer (score 0):

Basically you are creating a buyer model only inside addbulletin post route. 
What you can do is create a model for buyer inside models folder :

```
//models/buyer.js

var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var buyerSchema = new mongoose.Schema({ 
    //your_schema
}, { collection : 'buyer'});

var buyerModel = mongoose.model('buyer', buyerSchema);
```

Now import the model inside router and use it like below :

```
//routes.js

var buyer = require('./models/buyer');//make sure you write directory path correctly

app.get('/viewall',function(req,res)
{
    //now here below buyer is available as a model to use directly
  buyerModel.find({},function(err,docs){
   if(err){
    res.json(err);
   }
   else{
    res.render('display', { users : docs });
   }
});
```

Comment: @vikassingh Yes try this out. It will also help you structure and manage your code as modules effectively :)

Comment: i am editing my question i have implimented what u said but there are few problem if u can help..

Comment: Just Move var Schema = new mongoose.Schema({... and var buyer = mongoose.model('buyer', Schema); above the app.post('/addbulletin',function(){}); instead of keeping inside it. it will start working.

Comment: dear @mihir i have updated my question please have a look ..!!as you have suggested earlier i created a buyers.js which is my buyers schema inside models folder.Whereas on routers page i have defined a /addbulletin routes which on submit extract form data from transaction.ejs and stores in variable . next i trigger db.collection('buyer').insert({...  whih tries to insert values in buyers collection.. but it give db reference error